# Can't assign list value to json policy in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have in Terraform this policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "${source_ip}"
            }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

and i have a variable authorized_ip defined like this :

```
variable "authorized_ip" {
  default = [
    "x.x.x.x/x",
    "x.x.x.x/x",
  ]
}
```

Now i'm calling the Json policy this way :

```
data "template_file" "apigw_policy" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/template/apigateway_policy.json.template")}"

   vars = {
      source_ip = "${var.authorized_ip}"
   }
}
```

But i'm getting this error :

> Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "source_ip": string
>   required.

So Terraform is expecting a String instead of the list. 
How to transform the list to String to be able to have a result like that :

```
"IpAddress": {
   "aws:SourceIp": [
      "x.x.x.x/x",
      "x.x.x.x/x"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: According to https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/inappropriate-value-for-attribute-vars/26536/8 the `template_file` data source is deprecated and doesn't accept list vars. Use the `templatefile` function along with @ydaetskcoR answer below

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) here:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "${jsonencode(source_ip)}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"aws:SourceIp": ["${join(", ", source_ip)}"]
```

Note that `"[" and "]"` are outside of the interpolated value to define a list within the policy, but do not represent a Terraoform `list` type.

**Edit:** Fixed typo as mentioned in comment below.

Comment: Thank you it works, this is just a little typo "aws:SourceIp": ["${join(", ", source_ip)}"]